# Some plugins send mail but others don't. PHP mail function works but WordPress admin email won't

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a contradictory email deliverability issue. Thank you for any help you may be able to offer the community. I've read lots of articles, however, none of them work because they're all about finding what doesn't work and fixing that. Well, my WP email works but doesn't (please see below).

**Here's what doesn't work:**

- the verification email from WP backend to change the admin email address from settings > general
- most plugin emails (back and frontend) e.g. WooCommerce, [Ultimate Membership Pro](https://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-membership-pro-wordpress-plugin/12159253), and [Recover Abandon Cart](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-recover-abandoned-cart/7715167?_ga=2.59517161.554505166.1589918914-1667362536.1589918855).

*This issue is for all sites on this Goddady Cpanel hosting server.

**Here's what does work:**

- PHP mail function testing script found at [Media Template](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/360016044211/troubleshooting-common-issues-with-php-mail). It's just a form where you can manually send an email by calling the script from the URL that's in the root directory
- [Mailster](https://codecanyon.net/item/mailster-email-newsletter-plugin-for-wordpress/3078294) test emails from WP backend to any email address
- email sent to and from email addresses directly for affected sites (i.e info@mygtdata.com)

I've also installed and used the testing plugin [WP Mail Logging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-logging/) by MailPoet. My emails are being generated. Just not sent to the destination.

I've tried to send to Gmail email and other domain email addresses.

I've disabled all plugins and changed themes, to no avail.

**Try it yourself, if you'd like:**

[MyGTData](https://mygtdata.com/) is a testing site. Feel free to submit an order and see if you get an email. You won't.

Then, test my [PHP function](https://mygtdata.com/email.php). You will get an email, albeit in about 10min.

I don't know what else to look at. Please help or I'll just shut down my whole GoDaddy account. LOL

Thank you very much.

Formerlyanakin,

Comment: You may need to setup an SPF record on your domain to allow emails from your domain to sent: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-spf-record-19218

Comment: Thanks disinfor. I will try this right away.

Comment: No, disinfor. That did not work. I have SPF records for all of my domains. And, they are accurate. But, thank you for that information. I didn't even know about SPFs.

Comment: Does the test mail option in SMTP plugin sent email ?

Comment: No melvin, it does not. I used WP Mail SMTP by WPForms with "mailer" set to PHP (no SMTP).

Answer (score 0):

After hours more of trying to figure out this issue, the research consensus is that the cpanel+GoDaddy email system is convoluted. And when I called in, GoDaddy refused to troubleshoot Cpanel or my server because emailing the affected addresses directly worked. As we know, that doesn't mean that *nothing's* wrong.

Anyways, at a last-ditch effort, I reactivated and fully explored all of the Mailster plugin options; and it fixed the problem when I opted to allow it to handle "all" email for my Wordpress site. Here are my exact settings for Mailster:

1. Newsletter > Settings > Delivery >  "PHPs mail() function"
2. Newsletter > Settings > General > "Use Mailster for all outgoing WordPress mails"
3. Newsletter > Settings > Cron > "Use the wp_cron function to send newsletters"
   *I have my wp-cron job setup in https://www.easycron.com/. There is no need to use both a wp_cron job and a separate cron job for Mailster.

That's it. All plugins, including WooCommerce and WordPress send emails now.

Do I know exactly how? What does the Mailster plugin do? No. But I also don't know exactly how GoDaddy and Cpanel work.